# Disable ability to do a POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

I have API written in nodejs. I dont wany anyone to write anything (/post) into my app and my database, if he is not on my website.

I used `cors` library https://github.com/expressjs/cors

I tried: `app.use(cors())` aswell as directly inside my `/post` -

`app.get('/users', cors(), function() {})`

however it still doesnt work. I mean, I can turn on Postman application and send aswell /get and /post requests, with no any error!

I can even see that my headers changed: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin → https://example.com` (my domain) But i still can get data in postman.

Do I miss something? I dont care about get, but I dont want anyone to make POST requests to my database if he is not in my domain...

Comment: You should look at some kind of session/identity then. POST requests can come from a client which won't be on your domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Same Origin Policy is designed to stop attacking sites from *reading* data across origins (using the browser of a logged in user). CORS allows you to *relax* the Same Origin Policy. CORS weakens security, it doesn't increase it.

When people want to increase security, they generate apply defences against [CSRF attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), but that just prevents an attacking site from submitting data using the browser of a user your site trusts.

Your HTTP endpoints are public. You have to treat them as such.

You cannot control what people send to them.

You cannot force people to only send requests that your HTML forms, links and your JavaScript is designed to send.

You can only impose restrictions on what you do with the requests you get. Common examples include the requirement for the request to come from an authenticated / authorized user (e.g. username + password or OAuth), and rate limiting to stop a single source sending multiple accepted requests in a short span of time.

Comment: So whats the point actually of that library `cors`? Or it's totally useless?

Comment: CORS is not a library. It is an extension to the HTTP standard. (Well, you've found a library which implements CORS called the same thing). It allows you to weaken the Same Origin Policy when you want to allow the things it forbids.